# Get ActionScript Classes that Implement an Interface

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

In ActionScript (AS3) how do I find all the classes that implement a particular interface?

Comment: Are you asking in reference to Flex/AIR API classes, or any classes you've created or that are a part of third party components? If it's just the Flex & AIR APIs then the online doc's cover it for each interface. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html

Comment: What are you trying to do? Given IFoo, you want to generate a list of classes that have implemented it? What problem are you trying to solve? There might be a better solution.

Comment: If u want to use it in ur as3 code, u wud have to read the source files and parse them urself. If u just want to know the class names for reference, use ASDoc on the project and goto the page of corresponding interface. See for example: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/IFlexAsset.html

Comment: I need to do this at runtime.  It seems that I might be able to use this thing: http://etcs.ru/pre/getDefinitionNamesSource/ to do what I need.  I'll play around and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to do this and posted a [demo on my blog](http://www.jamesward.com/blog/2009/09/16/query-the-loaded-classes-in-flex-as3/).  It uses the getDefinitionNames library mentioned in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

In OOP terms, you never want to be able to do this: the primary characteristic of interfaces is they are terms of a contract. Any class can choose to fulfill that contract and be able to say "I implement this interface".

Any code that references an instance of the interface don't care what class actually implements it: they don't have to; that's the really cool part of interfaces.

But if you want to find out, grep for "implements IFred"

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In Flash Builder I use ctrl-h and search for method names or the actual name of the interface.

Comment: Thanks Ryan but I'm trying to do this at runtime, not development time.

Comment: Sorry should have read your blog post... That's really interesting. Thanks for sharing.