# FLASH count symbols in external text file

Tags: flash, actionscript

The problem is that i need to count symbols in external .txt file djs/1/text.txt
If this external text  file contains more than 50 symbols then i need to echo some text in Dynamic flash text(Myflashtext.htmlText ="some text";) in my Flashmovie.

Comment: The exact problem is that i can't count symbols in external file.IF statement  says that file is empty even when it's not...

Comment: Can you post the relevant code snippet.

Comment: i tried to count symbols in Dynamic text field where text is visible but Mytext.htmlText.length but it also says it's empty.

Comment: ///here's the code///<br></br>
d2 = new LoadVars();
d2.onLoad = function() {
tt12.html=true;
tt12.htmlText = this.djinfo ;
};
d2.load("djs/1/info.txt");

redline.html=true;
redline._visible=false;
redline.autoSize=true;
if (tt12.htmlText.length >50) then {
 redline.htmlText ="<font color='#"+990000+"'><b>there is text</b><font>"; } 
 else {
redline.htmlText ="<font color='#"+990000+"'><b>no text here</b><font>"; 
 }

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this manual work you're doing by writing all the existing symbols to a seperate Text file, you could use a solution that user:James Ward have recommended in the past.

See question & answer for: [Get ActionScript Classes that Implement an Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402193/get-actionscript-classes-that-implement-an-interface)

The use of `getDefinitionNames()` might come in handy for you.

Comment: Here's the direct link to obtain the Class that does this extraction process for you: etcs.ru/pre/getDefinitionNamesSource